# making one button send multiple commands

Tags: arduino

I'm making a robot using an arduino motherboard and an Ethernet shield. The Ethernet shield is setup so that if I type http://www.robotip.com/?1 it gives power to pin 1, if I type http://www.robotip.com/?2 it gives power to pin 2. So I have a button and rather then a normal button clicking it sends 1 command I would like to be able to hold the button and have it send ?1 every second that the button is held. What can i use to achieve this? I know this is a very confusing question lol thanks a lot.

Comment: Do not use tags that do not apply to your question

Comment: You could set up a small script in python on your pc that would perform an HTTP GET once per second. I'm assuming you're sending the commands from a web browser...

Answer (score 1):

If you're making a "control interface" with a webpage,

you should use javascript ([Jquery](http://jquery.com/) is a nice javascript library)

Using [get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) function you can send the commands asynchronous so it won't refresh the page every time you want to send some data to the robot.

And it also have a [mousedown](http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/) method, that is just what you want, it will do something while the mouse button is .. pressed.

Then you can put your timed requests inside the mousedown method.